# My bounty expired with no answers, how can I raise the bounty?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, expired-bounty

I asked a question on Stack Overflow ([How to update the deprecated python zipline.transforms module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347001/how-to-update-the-deprecated-python-zipline-transforms-module)) but received no answers. I offered a bounty of 50 reputation but still received no answers. I would like to raise the bounty to 100, but can't figure out how. Can someone provide a way to do this?

I looked at the blog [Improvements to Bounty System](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/19/improvements-to-bounty-system) provided by some answers to a similar question, but it doesn't detail exactly how to raise the bounty.

Could someone provide a simple approach to raising the bounty or tell me if it's not possible at all?

Comment: Post a new bounty? Same way you posted the original bounty.

Comment: You would have to wait for the grace period to end first though.

Answer (score 2):

Once the grace period is over, you'll be able to add a new bounty.

Note that you'll be *required* to make it larger than the last bounty; you can't simply keep a question in the "Featured" list by adding endless 50-point bounties to it.

Comment: Do you know how long the grace period is? It has been almost 24 hours since the bounty expired.

Comment: 24 hours. It's all detailed in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).